# Div position fixed scroll bar is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have made a pop box `<div id="popBox"> position:fixed; width:80%; height:80%;` at center of screen.

I use jQuery `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');` when it opens. So users wont scroll the content behind the pop box.

Here is the problem.

1.fixed - scroll bar wont appear when window scale down.

2.jQuery lock the body overflow-hidden. So the scroll bar will disappear.

Is any way to solve this problem?

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gAEut/

Comment: mind to share a fiddle or jsbin?

Comment: just update the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
```

or if you mean you want the popup to scroll , do this instead

```
$('#popBox').css('overflow', 'scroll');
```

Comment: 1 problem, i want the scroll bar appear at side of browser not the <div id="popBox"> and only appear when window small than the container

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scroll bar to appear when the content exceeds the size of container, then use

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `overflow:auto`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gAEut/1/)